# Best way to autogenerate React form from OpenAPI specification?

Tags: reactjs, fastapi, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm using FastAPI, which is able to generate an OpenAPI specification.

I've also used `openapi-typescript-codegen` to generate a client to connect to FastAPI. It autogenerates types like the following:

```
export type Message = {
    role: string;
    content: string;
};
```

Is it possible to autogenerate a React form using either of the openapi.json spec or the type?

I've looked into `react-jsonschema-form` but that doesn't seem to work because it doesn't read files (https://github.com/rjsf-team/react-jsonschema-form/issues/1029).

Comment: I don't quite get this question. APIs and forms are two totally different things. On the front end an API client and a form don't have any innate relation. You'd probably have to roll something yourself to go from API type spec -> form spec object -> dynamically generated form.

Comment: JSONForms is a similar project that can use local files. however, it's not fully compatible with swagger json, which brought me here